# In Experience Manager new RTF content is not saving

Tags: experience-manager

I am facing issue while adding a new content on a page through experience manager. The issue is only with a text field, for which I am using a RTF. Other fields of component is saving correctly. The issue appears only when I created new component from XPM.

I also observed that issue doesn't appear only when the content type(used to create new components) has some value in rich text field.

Can anyone suggest the root cause..

Comment: When you say the content is not saving do you mean that it says your changes are saved but the updates aren't showing up or are you getting an error?

Comment: Changes of RTF text field only not saved, other fields got saved and update on page..

Comment: Can you verify that you can save the component in the CME with exactly the same RTF content? You could be the victim of a rich text field XSLT filter here...